# How to set the return value in joblib's cache explicitly?

Tags: python, joblib

I want to set the cached value of a function for a given argument list using [joblib's Memory](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html). Something like this:

```py
from joblib import Memory

memory = Memory('cachedir')

@memory.cache
def f(x):
    # Placeholder for a heavy task
    print('Running f(%s)' % x)
    return 'Return and store this string %s' % x

# The following line isn't working, but I want something similar:
memory.set_cached_value(f, 1234, 'Return and store this string 1234')
```

I know that the simplest way is to call `f` with the given arguments (`1234`). But in my case (sometimes) the result is available without calculation so I want to set without calling the heavy `f`.

Is there any similar (working) to: `memory.set_cached_value(f, 1234, 'Return and store this string 1234')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to use ignored arguments:

```py
from joblib import Memory

memory = Memory('cachedir')

@memory.cache(ignore=['force_val'])
def f(x, force_val=None):
    if force_val is not None:
        return force_val
    # Placeholder for a heavy task
    print('Running f(%s)' % x)
    return 'Return and store this string %s' % x

# Set explicitly:
f(1234, 'Return and store this string 1234')
```